# Wireless bridge DNS issues

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, bridge

I just moved into a new place, and now use Comcast's Cisco 105+ as a cable modem/wifi gateway.

I've set up my Buffalo WZR-300HP (DD_WRT v24 SP2) as a wireless bridge, using the "Client Bridge (Routed)" setting as my Wireless Mode.

Cisco (primary router) IP: 10.0.0.1
Buffalo (secondary) IP: 10.0.0.2

In the secondary router, I've set my gateway and DNS to 10.0.0.1.  However, after 5 minutes or so, any machine connected via LAN to the secondary router will lose DNS.  The only thing that fixes it is a computer reboot or disable/enable the network adapter, which I'm assuming refreshes DNS for *something*?

I'm guessing there's more info needed, so please let me know if that's the case.  Otherwise, any thoughts?

[image: primary router settings]

[image: secondary router settings]

Comment: You want to do it the other way.  Ask comcast to put the Cisco in bridge mode and use it as a modem only.  (I've gotten to the correct people at comcast to make this happen in the past by tweeting DM's to @ComcastCares.)

Comment: Is there a reason I should use the Cisco in bridge mode?  I'm baffled why my setup wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you disable the DHCP server on the Buffalo? Also,some guides on the Net suggest leaving the DNS box empty, in the secondary router (the Buffalo). Did you try this? Reference: bullet17 here,  http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Bridged

Comment: If I remove DHCP on the Buffalo, that means I will have to hardcode the IP  address for any device that connects to it, right?

Comment: If disabling the network adapter or rebooting the computer fixes the DNS issue, then the DNS issue isn't anything to do with the wireless bridge. 

All that does, is refresh the settings between the computer and the Buffalo router.  What you need to test is whether the computer loses all connectivity, and/or whether it still has a DHCP address. The "ipconfig /all" and "ping <whatever the IP of the Buffalo router is>" should help.

Comment: Another thing which you haven't specified is the subnet that is used behind the secondary router.

Comment: No, it means it will forward the request to the main router. It is dangerous having two DHCP servers on the same subnet... it can be done but care must be taken. Let me know the result of this experiment.

Comment: I've added screenshots with the primary (the first image) and the secondary (the second image) settings.  I have tried to set the DNS in the secondary to 0.0.0.0, but that hasn't worked so far.

Comment: No, sorry, not 0.0.0.0, which means **any** address. I was proposing to leave that **blank**, as per the Web page linked above.

Comment: I'm unable to set the Local DNS values to blank (DD-WRT does not allow a blank value).

Comment: Why does the router have no local DNS setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings for the primary are wrong: the initial DHCP address cannot be *10.0.0.2* because that is already taken, in a static lease, by the Buffalo.

Also, the two ranges overlap. You should separate them. For instance, in router 1 use the range

```
        10.0.0.32-10.0.0-95
```

and in the Buffalo use

```
        10.0.0.160-10.0.0.223
```

In this way, there will be no conflict.

Comment: Didn't you suggest to not use DHCP in the Buffalo? (sorry if I'm misunderstanding the part about the range for the Buffalo)

Comment: @Matt What I suggested is to prevent the two DHCP servers to interfere.You achieve that either by having non-overlapping ranges,or turning off the DHCP server on the Buffalo altogether.You may try each solution, in any case your LAN cannot work as it is.

Comment: I believe the DHCP issue was the crux of my problem.  I'm going to give it a little more time, but so far I think this will ultimately be the answer (and I'll mark it as so if nothing else pops up).